# How to change the width of a Pin Widget in Pinterest

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, widget, pinterest

I want to add a Pin Widget to my website. I want the pins width `300px`, but by default the pins are coming in `237px`. I couldn't find any option to change the width of Pin Widget on the Pinterest website.

How can I change the width of the Pin Widget?

The code generated by widget builder is given below:

```
<a data-pin-do="embedPin" href="http://www.pinterest.com/pin/469007748667270308/"></a>
<!-- Please call pinit.js only once per page -->
<script type="text/javascript" async src="//assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

This is coming in `237px`, but I want the width to be `300px`.

Answer (score 0):

In the [Widget Builder](http://business.pinterest.com/en/widget-builder) you don't seem to be able to do this. You can switch from small to large and maybe adjust the height. My solution was to put Pinterest on the end of my row of buttons so it could have all the space it needed to the right.

Pinterest has a lot less sophisticated JavaScript share button than Facebook, Twitter, or Google+. Pinterest is about minimalism and midwest housewifes and their dreams and aspirations.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap inside the  element. Below snippet

```
    <div class="someclass" style="max-width:300px; overflow:hidden;">
<a data-pin-do="embedPin" href="http://www.pinterest.com/pin/469007748667270308/"></a></div>
```

Its not an ideal solution. But it can fix your requirement temporarily.